# Will bill Pugh singleton solution would work on objective c ?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I know bill Pugh is thread safe and recommend way to use.
I searched a lot about it in the internet but couldn't find an answer.
is bill Pugh solution will work on objective c as well ? 
I know it will work on java, but do some of you have experience in objective c?

Answer (score 1):

Had to look up The "Bill Pugh singleton".

Sure, it could be used in Objective-C, but why bother?   There is already a perfectly good singleton pattern in wide use in ObjC (that largely implements the same pattern anyway;  the singleton is only created on first access).

Comment: The Bill Pugh singleton solution is thread safe as I recall, regardless if you using synchronize or atomic, at least it is the best way in java... was really curious about Objective c.

Comment: @XcodeNOOB The standard pattern in ObjC is thread safe, as well, using dispatch_once() to ensure exclusive creation of the singleton.